# Read First n Bits in a Byte Array in Scala

Tags: scala, bit

I have a Byte array as for example:

```
0 240 167 43 200 209 57 213 1 89 182 103 60 43 0 0
```

I would now want to read the first 3 bits of this Byte array:

Here is how I read this as a Byte array:

```
  val bytes = "0 240 167 43 200 209 57 213 1 89 182 103 60 43 0 0".getBytes("utf-8")
```

Now from this Byte array what I have, I should be able to read the whole sequence bit by bit. For example., the first 3 bits represent a certain value, the next 4 another value and like that. I have the rules for what these values mean, but I just don't know how I can do such a bit operation on the Byte array that I have!

Any pointers on how to get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to convert a Seq[Byte] into an Array[Boolean] representing each bit in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267771/how-to-convert-a-seqbyte-into-an-arrayboolean-representing-each-bit-in-scala)

Here's how to turn single byte into an array of bits.
You can turn you bytes array into bits by simply calling

```
val bits = bytes.flatMap(byte2Bools)
```

and then get first 3 bits as

```
bits.take(3)
```

Comment: How to then get the value out of the first 3 bits? Now with this I get the Boolean, but how do I turn that into a value?

Comment: true <==> 1  false <==> 0

Answer (score 2):

have you tried `bytes(0) & 0xE0` this gets use the left most 3 bits
(0xE0 is the 11100000 binary mask)

... try `(255 & 0xE0) >> 5` to have them shifted into an integer

you'll probably want the first 3 bits of the first byte: `(bytes(0) & 0x07)`

(0x07 is the 00000111 binary mask)